# Python API GET/POST Unique JSON Records

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, http, python-requests

I've created Python script which makes a GET request to infrastructure monitoring tool to fetch a json object of problems that occurred in the last 30 days. All these problems have unique ids.

After that, it makes a POST request to push this json object record by record to another API end-point.

I want to attach this script to cron job to execute it every 5 minutes, but I could not figure out a way to only get or post previously not sent events. So it always fetches a list of problems in the last 30 days and it pushes all of them.

I thought about writing this json to local file and comparing it with the latest request, but then the previously fetched records also becomes considered new. So I am stuck and couldn't find a similarly asked question. I am open to all suggestions as long as things do not get too complicated :)

Comment: Does the API provided by this "infrastructure monitoring tool" not have any way to filter for records created after a certain date? That way you can `GET` only these records that your script hasn't possibly seen before, and simply store the date of the last run.

Comment: So you mean only get the problems that occured in the last 5 minutes and also execute the script every 5 minutes? Yes, the tool is called Dynatrace, and I can do what you suggest. But I also wonder how can I proceed if this was not possible?

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to include the name of the product as well as the specific endpoint(s) you’re using?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to keep a local file in your preferred format that tracks the unique IDs of all items you've pushed, ever. Load that in with your cron'd script, and then do your pull. Compare each item in the pull against your cached values, and generate a list of new items to push. Add these items to your cached values variable, push the items, and then write the entirety of your cached values out to file. A potentially faster (in terms of I/O, if your file gets large) way of doing this would be to keep all the values in the file, one per line, and then just open the file with "append" mode and write out only the new values to it, one per line.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of persistence.

You can save a file with the timestamp of the most recent event.

Then, the next time the script executes, it only POSTs events with a timestamp later than the one in the saved file, and then updates the saved file.

If the API to which you're POSTing has a way to fetch the last event you sent to it (NOT the last event it received from *any* client), you don't even need the file, the API is your persistence.